# Filtering JSON Data on the Browser/Client

Tags: json

Here's the scenario-- you've got a JSON object on the browser, and let's say it has a boolean property, called "Active". We want to create a new JSON object that contains only items that have Active = True. Is there an easy way to do this, other than looping through the entire JSON object?

I'm basically trying to use ASP.Net AJAX Templates to show a list of items that can either be active or inactive, based on a dropdown the user selects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out:

- [JSLINQ](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/)
- Steele's [Functional](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/)
- [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)